# Change variables in arduino sketch?

Tags: vb.net, windows, cmd, arduino

I have an Arduino file (.ino) that i want to modify.
I thought about 2 ways in which i can do this:

1.I make a program in vb net that sends serial signals and based on that signals my arduino board is programmed to change a certain variabile.This seems like a good idea but after you reset the arduino board the variable value is lost

2.I change the arduino code immediately before i compile it and upload it the the board, this is what i do now but it gets kinda tricky because you have to modify a lot of files and the encodings change and so on.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: You need to be more clear about how the file needs modified. Do you need to change a value based on some attribute of the board, an external sensor, what? You could also try searching the [Arduino SE](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/) for similar concepts (but I am sure they would want you to clarify before posting as well).

Comment: I want something like : I have a program with a slider from 0 to 10 that changes a value in the program like the intensity of a led, i change it through serial everything is ok but after i want that value to remain the same until i change it again (even if i restart the board)

Comment: @AlexSimion what you are looking for is a permanent storage. Think about your PC: if you open a webpage, it is stored in RAM. If the PC reboots, you lose that webpage. In order to have it the next reboot you have to download it and save to the hard drive. Now, a variable is stored in RAM. If you want to get it back after a reboot, you have to store it on a persistent storage. Most of microcontrollers have an inbuilt EEPROM just for this purpose. Look [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROM) and.. beware of the wearing of this memory (for instance use update instead of write)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said here, you should modify your code to persist the changes to EEPROM, either the built in one or in the alternative to a replaceable external EEPROM like "FRAM" that is available cheaply ($6.00) from many suppliers.

At an average of 100,00 writes lifetime you should be OK with the internal EEPROM unless you are changing the slider too often.  Do the math:

100 changes daily would last approximately 2 to 2.5 years of use.  If this is not sufficient for you then get an external FRAM pack which will last an exponentially longer time.